# Can I make a valid entity that consists *only* of relationships? (No attributes)

Tags: core-data

[image: Data Model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no reason why the answer is no.

You can easily select any set of attributes/relations you want.

At least, you could try and see if it crashed)But, really,it wouldn't)